# Huffman coding for non-dyadic distribution

Tags: huffman-coding

I have a question regarding the methodology of Huffman coding. So, is there a Huffman coding methodology that approximates the minimum average number of bits per decimal character when the odds of information symbols are not powers of 2? I can't understand or find anything relevant

Comment: Question 1: What is a “Huffman coding methodology”?

Comment: Question 2: The Huffman algorithm as I know it, is not restricted to powers of 2. Why do you think it is?

Comment: I can't make any sense of what you are saying. Please try to answer my question to clarify what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Huffman's algorithm solves the following problem. Given a distribution $P=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$, find a prefix code $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ which minimizes the expected codeword length $$ \sum_{i=1}^n p_i |w_i|. $$
If $p_i = 2^{-\ell_i}$ then the optimal solution has $|w_i| = \ell_i$, and the resulting expected codeword length is exactly the entropy of $P$, but Huffman's algorithm works for any distribution.

If we call a distribution in which $p_i = 2^{-\ell_i}$ *dyadic* (there is no common term in the literature), then Huffman's algorithm "rounds" an arbitrary distribution $P$ into a dyadic distribution $Q$ which minimizes the Kullback–Leibler divergence $D(P\|Q)$.

We can get closer to the entropy of $P$ by encoding together groups of symbols. If you encode $m$-tuples of symbols together, then the expected codeword length *per symbol* (i.e., dividing the expression above by $m$) is at most $H(P) + 1/m$, and in particular, it tends to the entropy as $m \to \infty$. Shannon's source coding theorem shows that you cannot go below the entropy using *any* encoding scheme, so using Huffman coding in blocks is asymptotically optimal as the block size goes to infinity.

Comment: Can I try rephrasing what you've said here to see if I understand it? So, there's some inefficiency in Huffman coding for a uniform distribution on an alphabet that doesn't have $2^n$ symbols, since some binary sequences are "wasted", but the wastage shrinks if we encode blocks of symbols together.

Comment: We consider arbitrary distributions, not only uniform distributions.

Comment: Oh sure. I was just thinking about the simple case of the uniform distribution, where it's basically just like a block code. So in that case, if you have say 30 symbols, then the best  you can do is have each letter encoded by a 5 digit binary sequence, and you have two left over sequences (what I called "waste" earlier). Is that kind of what's going on?